# Help identifying the plant

Tags: identification, plant-care

I received theses flowers and I would like to succeed growing them.

Would appreciate your help identifying them and tips for raising them! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The two outer ones are kalanchoe (search the site for more), the middle one is a bit harder: could we get a close up of the flowers and foliage?

Comment: Yes, Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, the centre one appears to be a pot Chrysanthemum, although seeing the foliage would confirm or deny

Comment: @Bamboo do you want to make an answer? i agree on the ID

Comment: @J.Musser yep, done, though I imagine by now, its extra to requirements!

Answer (score 1):

The two white flowered ones are Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, and the pink one in the middle is a pot Chrysanthemum. Unfortunately, this display is only meant to be temporary - the shallowness of the pot they're in means they won't continue to look good ongoing. Kalanchoe blossfeldiana is a houseplant in many areas of the world, anywhere that gets frosty winters; the pot Chrysanthemum can be moved into a larger pot or into the ground, but when it grows next year, it will be much, much taller.